# User home share persistently inaccessible in default profile after using `runas`

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, runas

I'm in an environment where much of our profile information is redirected to a network share (e.g. `\\foo\Home\myuser`)

Recently, I was attempting to access a network share as `otheruser`, and after rebooting and logging in the next day I cannot access my own `myuser` network share (so my normal desktop doesn't show, Visual Studio iisexpress won't start, etc).

The only commands I did when I used `runas` with `otheruser` were directory listing commands (with all the various `/profile`, `/noprofile`, `/env` options at different times), so I can't imagine how that would have corrupted my default profile, however, it is highly suggestive that although I cannot access `\\foo\Home\myuser`, I *can* access `\\foo\Home\otheruser` without error (the directory listing is empty).

If I now runas myself with `/noprofile` (e.g. `runas /noprofile /user:mydomain\myuser powershell`), the situation is reversed - I *can* access `\\foo\Home\myuser` but cannot access `\\foo\Home\otheruser`.

I also note that the error message for accessing `\\foo\Home\myuser` is `An unexpected network error occurred` rather than a simple "access denied" error. However, accessing `adifferentuser` sometimes gives one error and sometimes another, so I'm not sure that's relevant.

So it appears that somehow something in my user profile got corrupted / swapped. I'm at a loss as to where to go next - I've not found anything suggestive doing a textual search for `otheruser` in the registry.

Powershell transcript below:

```
#############################################################
# Under "normal" powershell window launched from start menu #
# (logged in as mydomain\myuser)                            #
#############################################################
PS C:\> whoami
mydomain\myuser
PS C:\>
PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\myuser\
dir : An unexpected network error occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir \\foo\Home\myuser\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\foo\Home\myuser\:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\otheruser
PS C:\>
PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\adifferentuser\
dir : Access to the path '\\foo\Home\adifferentuser\` is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir \\foo\Home\adifferentuser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\foo\Home\adifferentuser\:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\> runas /noprofile /user:mydomain\myuser powershell
Enter the password for mydomain\myuser
Attempting to start powershell as user "mydomain\myuser"
PS C:\>
```

```
##########################################################################
# Under new powershell window running as mydomain\myuser with /noprofile #
##########################################################################
PS C:\> whoami
mydomain\myuser
PS C:\>
PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\myuser

Mode            LastWriteTime   Length  Name
----            -------------   ------  ----
d-----   7/12/2022    7:07 AM           SomeDir
d-r---   10/5/2022    5:38 PM           Documents

PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\otheruser
dir : An unexpected network error occurred
At line:1 char:1
+ dir \\foo\Home\otheruser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\foo\Home\otheruser\:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\> dir \\foo\Home\adifferentuser
dir : A unexpected network error occurred.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir \\foo\Home\adifferentuser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\foo\Home\adifferentuser\:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\>
```

Comment: You cannot use both non-admin and admin users to map a share, or you will get errors like you did.  Easy out: Get the network administrator to remake the user folders and then just use a regular user.

Comment: I think I did try some commands in a powershell "run as administrator", though it appears to me the `runas` does not inherit that administrator access when I launch a new powershell prompt via `runas`.  I think I did also try to map a network drive under `\\foo\ashare` (not `\\foo\Home\*`) as `otheruser`.

Comment: This sounds like offline files nonsense. Go into control panel, I’m willing to bet offline files is enabled. Try turning it off.

Comment: @Appleoddity - thanks for the suggestion.  I checked "Offline files" and it was already disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

1. From the start menu, launch "Credential Manager"
2. Click "Windows Credentials"

   - This will be divided into three sections:

     1. Windows Credentials
     2. Certificate-Based Credentials
     3. Generic Credentials
3. Remove any stored credentials that are a parent to the path giving difficulty. Examine all 3 sections.

   - In my case, I removed an entry for `foo` from both the "Windows Credentials" and "Generic Credentials" sections

## Explanation

It appears that during my attempts with `runas` or perhaps some other attempt to map a drive at a `\\foo\adirectory` (not a subdirectory of `\\foo\Home\`), that credentials were stored in Windows Credential Manager for the `foo` "Internet or network address" with the `otheruser` credentials.

Having the credentials stored in Credential Manager was a side-effect of some other operation - I never added them explicitly to credential manager.

However, the behavior [appears to be consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634095/24954) with the `/savecred` option to `runas`.  So it's likely I tried that option at one point (though I don't have an explicit memory/record of doing so).

Thus any attempts to access *any* sub-path of the root `\\foo\` were using the `otheruser` credentials, which explains the odd behavior.

Removing the credentials from credential manager under the "Windows Credentials" section and rebooting resolved the problem.

After rebooting, I saw another "generic credential" also for `foo` with `otheruser`.  I removed that also.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.